# How to pass parameter to path in url_for FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am an absolute newbie to FastAPI and faced a pretty strange problem. While trying to display an image by its name (which is the same as id), I just cannot pass the name to the template.
To make it clear, everything works fine if I just hardcode the id, but the question is how to pass it automatically?
Here is my main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/items/{id}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_item(request: Request, id: str):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("item.html", {"request": request, "id": id})
```

And here is my template.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item Details</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Item ID: {{ id }}</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', path='/qr-codes/{{ id }}.png') }}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But this line: `<img src="{{ url_for('static', path='/qr-codes/{{ id }}.png') }}"/>` doesn't work as {{ id }} isn't seen as a parameter.

So my question is how can I pass my parameter to path in url_for?
Thanks for every responce!

Comment: `path='/qr-codes/' + id + '.png')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In item.html, change the img src path value to the below:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', path='/qr-codes/'+ id + '.png') }}" />
```

Request URL:

> http://localhost:8000/items/1

OpenApi (Swagger) Output

```
<h1>Item ID: 1</h1>
<img src="http://localhost:8000/static/qr-codes/1.png" />
```

***Note:*** Concatenate the string using `'+'` gives the formatted value

Comment: It seems so easy, yet it works perfectly. Thank you so much!